# shows "fragmentManager cannot be resolved" , working through Android 4.0 Tutorial 12

Tags: android, fragmentmanager

Everything else is good except the "fragmentManager" cannot be resolved, what am I doing wrong here? The tutorial skipped over some parts on this section...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity_frame);
    FragmentManager frgman = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction frgtrans = frgman.beginTransaction();
    Fragment frag = new Side_Fragment();
    frgtrans.replace(R.id.frag_frame, frag, "SIDE");
    frgtrans.commit();
}

public void swapFrag(View v) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManger = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    Fragment current = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("SIDE");

    if(!current.isVisible())
    {
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_frame,  picture, "PIC");
    }
    else
    {
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_frame,  side, "SIDE");            
    }
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Use `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: and also need to `import android.app.FragmentManager`